# Do higher frequency EM waves travel longer than lower EM frequency waves?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, scattering, frequency, radio-frequency, absorption

In radio communication, the distance traveling seems to be an important parameter before we choose the frequency band of communication.

There is also a path-loss model that describes a distance $\leftrightarrow$ frequency dependence of the attenuation with an isotropic antenna.

However, I fail to find any specific physical law that demonstrates the frequency dependence of the attenuation. Some even say that higher the frequency, higher the energy content.  What are the factors for propagation distance?

Comment: Which kind of waves are you talking of?

Comment: I'm afraid this is too broad a question at the moment. You need to be more precise e.g. are you talking about sound waves, light waves, water waves, or something else? The second paragraph is a separate question and should be posted separately. Google [black body radiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation) for some background reading before you post.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but I believe this is related to the fact that an EM wave can only interact/be absorbed by objects which greater than of equal to its wavelength.

Comment: @DarioP and John
I have rephrased my question, hopefully clarifies your points.

Comment: @fibonatic
sorry, I fail to get the link between your comment and my Q.  I think we can safely assume that there are objects of all lengths in this world, required for the waves under consideration!

Comment: It depends a lot on the medium that you are choosing for the propagation and, unless you choose vacuum, there is not a trivial function.

Comment: @HarisharioP I am sorry, I think I misinterpreted your question (I thought you where talking about a very wide range of EM radiation). And I think I can give you a better answer, like DarioP said, it depends on the emission/absorption spectra of the medium the EM radiation is traveling through. The [Beer-Lambert law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beer-Lambert_Law) describes this. However you still need to know the absorption spectra of the medium.

Answer (score 1):

If you search for "atmospheric attenuation vs wavelenghth" you will find many charts like this:  They show that in our atmosphere there is not a simple relationship between wavelength and transmission.  The various gases in the atmosphere contribute to the spectrum.

[image]